# How do I import images in Gatsby v2?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm learning to build static sites using Gatsby v2 and encountering a problem:

When I try to import a logo.svg file from the images folder, it does not work. (See attached screenshot)

[image]

I checked in the console, it says the logo is defined but never used? I'm not too sure what exactly i did wrong here. Any pointers would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSX syntax is wrong. It has to be `<img src={logo} />` without the double quotes. Have a look at the React docs if that is unclear to you :)

Comment: uh! such a rookie mistake! thank you for pointing it out for me!